# Signing PDF with Java itext library crashing for big files

Tags: java, exception, itext, digital-signature

I am using Itext library for PDF signing which works fine for small files under 50MB. But file which are larger in size are getting crash like if file size is 150MB then it gives

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ByteBuffer.append(ByteBuffer.java:210)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ByteBuffer.write(ByteBuffer.java:622)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:105)
at java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(FilterOutputStream.java:80)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.OutputStreamCounter.write(OutputStreamCounter.java:104)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PRStream.toPdf(PRStream.java:230)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfIndirectObject.writeTo(PdfIndirectObject.java:157)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter$PdfBody.write(PdfWriter.java:397)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter$PdfBody.add(PdfWriter.java:386)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter.addToBody(PdfWriter.java:848)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamperImp.close(PdfStamperImp.java:353)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamperImp.close(PdfStamperImp.java:327)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfSignatureAppearance.preClose(PdfSignatureAppearance.java:1244)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeSignature.signDetached(MakeSignature.java:134)
```

here is my signing code which works fine for less than 50 MB pdf files

```
     private void PdfSigningProcess(String src, String dest,
        Certificate[] chain,
        PrivateKey pk, String digestAlgorithm, String provider,
        MakeSignature.CryptoStandard subfilter, String reason, String location)
        throws
        GeneralSecurityException, IOException, DocumentException
  {
    // Creating the reader and the stamper
    PdfReader reader =
            new PdfReader(src);
    FileOutputStream os =
            new FileOutputStream(dest);
    PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.
            createSignature(reader, os, '\0');
    //Creating the appearance PdfSignature Appearance
    PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();
    appearance.setReason(reason);
    appearance.setLocation(location);
    appearance.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(36, 7, 48, 144, 780), 1, "DQCA Signature");
    // Creating the signature 
    ExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
    ExternalSignature signature =
            new PrivateKeySignature(pk, digestAlgorithm, provider);
    MakeSignature.signDetached(appearance, digest, signature, chain, null, null, null, 0, subfilter); //HERE IT IS CRASHING
}
```

"MakeSignature.signDetached" this is the function where exception coming ... kindly guide me how to fix this issue since the writing and appending process is inside this function which i cant change and flush data line by line...

Comment: I'd be surprised if this has anything to do with iText. Have you tried increasing your heap space? How big is your heap space now?

Comment: netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-XX:PermSize=32m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true -J-Dsun.awt.disableMixing=true"  this is what i got from my netbeans.config ...do you mean this file config to see heapsize?

Comment: In addition to Bruno's hint, please switch to using a PdfReader constructor which does not cause the whole PDF document to be parsed into memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see that you've read my [white paper](http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures), but I also see that you choose to sign documents in memory. As Michaël indicates, you shouldn't blame iText for using plenty of memory if you're asking iText to use plenty of memory ;-)

Please read section 2.2.4 entitled "Signing large PDF files". In that section, you'll find an example showing how to sign using a temporary file. This will reduce the memory use significantly.

Don't overlook the note: if you use the `createSignature()` method with a temporary file, you can use an `OutputStream` that is `null`, in that case, the temporary file will serve as the actual destination file. This is good practice if your goal is to store a signed file on your file system. If the `OutputStream` is not `null`, iText will always try to delete the temporary file after the signing is done.

Comment: Thanks Bruno ... i didn't realize that it contain this topic explicitly